# How selecting rows after caltulation of each row's quantiles?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, quantile

I have a big dataframe with numerical values (12579 rows and 21 columns) from which I would like to extract those columns that fit in the first and the fourth quartile of each row (every row has independent values).

That is why I have calculated each row's quantiles in order to obtain two cutoffs by row.

```r
library(matrixStats)
d_q1 <- rowQuantiles(delta, probs = c(0.25, 0.75))

delta2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(delta,d_q1))
dim(delta2) # 12579    23

library(dplyr)
delta2 <- filter(delta2, delta2[,1:21] <= `25%` & delta2[,1:21] >= delta2$`75%`)
```

I expected getting those values in Q1 and Q4. However, when I tried to filter the values, I always obtain an error message:

```r
Error: Result must have length 12579, not 264159
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Elena, please `dput()` a sample of your data so that we can try your code. What output are you expecting? It's unclear if you expect a variable number of columns to be returned for each row (e.g., columns 1-2 for row 1, columns 3-5 for row 2, etc.).

Comment: Hi kstew, I just realised I cannot achieve what I wanted this way. As you said, it's unclear and I should redesign my experiment. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying here, but my guess is that you want for each row the values smaller than Q1 and larger than Q3. In that case this line should work for you.

```
t(apply(delta, 1, sort))[,c(1:6, 16:21)]
```

Regarding your code, dplyr::filter() doesn't work that way, it is meant to give you a subset of the rows in your dataframe, so its arguments need to be logical vectors of the same length as the number of rows in your dataframe.

Comment: Hi shs, Thank you for answering. My aim was selecting the most significant rows, but I did not design the experiment properly from the very begining (I thought I should select values smaller than Q1 and larger than Q3, as you mention). After trying several possibilities, I realised I should perform a PCA analysis and check the distribution of the data. Thank you again!